# Can I install sudo/su with the signed apk exploit?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, nexus-4, root-access, apk

The [BlueBox Security Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bluebox.labs.onerootscanner) says that my Nexus 4 is still vulnerable to two signature exploits.

As far as I understood the exploit can circumvent the apk-signature-check so that any apk posing as an update for a system-apk will be installed as system app.

Is there a known way to install sudo/su with this exploit?

I would like to do so before my Nexus gets patched...

**Update 2013-07-22:**

What I am looking for is a step by step guide along these lines:

1. get sudo-apk
2. choose one unused system-app
3. remove updates for this system-app
4. download latest update for this system-app
5. integrate sudo-apk with system-app-update-apk
6. install
7. have joy

Comment: As you correctly wrote: *any apk posing as an update for a system-apk will be installed as system app*. But an update requires something to be already there which it can update -- otherwise it's simply a fresh install. I might be wrong, but to me that means a clear "No".

Comment: @Izzy how about that "Google Korean keyboard" that I deactivated? This is a firmware-app with pending updates.

Comment: Try it and tell us. That *might* do, but I'm not sure what your SuperUser app is named then :) And being an update, it would *replace* that keyboard (or whatever system app you would "update"), so be careful and beware side-effects.

Comment: @Izzy I would love to try it - but I need a step by step installation. The name of the apk should be correct - if I undestood what BlueBox wrote about this.

Comment: For that I'm out: cannot give you that "step-by-step" guide.

Comment: Anyway, the app will still require root to touch to /system and so to install the su binary. What I mean is that system app doesn't have more root access than a "normal" app. You'll still have to found a root exploit to gain temporary privilege.

Comment: That's exactly the point: For `su` to work, it must be in the `$PATH`. To modify that accordingly, `/system` must be mounted r/w -- and that doesn't happen even when a system app is updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Exploit (& Fix) Android "Master Key"](http://www.saurik.com/id/17) article describes the process of using the “Master Key” exploit to get elevated privileges with lots of technical details. The main point is that the exploit by itself does not give root privileges — only arbitrary code execution as the `system` user, and another privilege elevation exploit is needed to get root privileges (one well-known example shown in the article is writing `ro.kernel.qemu=1` to `/data/local.prop`, but this attack is blocked in most Android 4.1 and later versions).

The article also provides download links for the Cydia Impactor tool which automates the “Master Key” exploit (currently only up to getting the `system` user rights, not all the way to root). There are versions for [Windows](https://cydia.saurik.com/api/latest/2) and [Mac OS X](https://cydia.saurik.com/api/latest/1).

Answer (score 1):

The exploit is patched into AOSP, currently in CyanogenMod, its a matter of time before the update gets pushed out. It does not give you root privilege per se, rather it circumvents the signed key used to sign the ROM so that an apk can pose as a system app, in which the installation of the apk bypasses the said signed key.

As you have a Nexus 4, it will be a matter of time before Google pushes that out.

As for others, best to check with your manufacturer, *not* your carrier.